# Override a wildcard dynamic route template

Tags: templating, url, routes, routing, segments

I have a dynamic route for individual user `/profiles`. I expected it would be possible to override this route for `/profiles/all` but apparently not.

This can be achieved in the template I expect, with a conditional statement on the url `.segment(2)`, but it would save a little time if it was possible to override a wildcard route.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort order matters, move the more specific route up and you should be good. Alternativly set it up in routes.php using some regular expressions.

Comment: Ah! That actually makes sense when I think about it, working now ... thanks!